# Unrelated HDFS files disappearing on insert overwrite

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I recently had a number of HDFS files (which backed all my Hive tables) suddenly disappear.  The admin says that it was caused by an INSERT OVERWRITE query:

`insert overwrite table [table1] select [column] from [table2] as e lateral view explode(e.col) t as words;`

And yes, I know you can't insert a lateral view - now.

The question is - how can an insert overwrite for a single table delete the data for every table in the database... or can it?

Comment: Update:  The admin apparently restored the files in HDFS, but I still get no results from Hive queries.  I am assuming that whatever mapping Hive has to HDFS files has to be rebuilt?  Would that also mean that whatever deleted the files happened outside of Hive?

Comment: Did you find out what caused this? I have a similar issue.